#  VideoView audio only, no video?

Tags: android

I have a Video view in my activity used to display a video stored in my res.raw folder like this:

```
MediaController controller=new MediaController(this);
video.setMediaController(controller);
String filePath="android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video3;
video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(filePath));
video.requestFocus();
video.start();
```

The problem is that I can hear the audio only, but the video is not shown.

What can be the reason for this?

**Edit:** here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/btnPlayAudio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play Audio"
        >
        </Button>
        <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnPlayVideo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play Video"
        >
        </Button>

        <VideoView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/videoView"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: And were do you assign the MediaPlayer to the VideoView? Have you looked at: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/VideoViewDemo.html

Comment: Did you try to play this video with standart android player? And second question: you run your code on emulator or on device? Emulator may have problems with video playback.

Comment: @Blundell: I just use the code above. @Anton: I tried on a real device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I got it,

the problem was that my VideoView had width and height set to **wrap_content** when I changed to **fill_parent**, the video appeared

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your overcomplicating it :-)

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mp.start();
```

Linky: [Play from Raw Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#playraw)

Comment: Thanks for response, I tried your code but still I hear the audio only and no video is displayed

Comment: What format is your video in? Have you tried a different video?

Comment: the video is 3gp, I tried several videos including mp4 but the same things happen, I test this on HTC Desire phone.

Comment: It must be to do with how you draw the MediaPlayer to the screen then

Comment: would you please explain more ?

Comment: Put your code up of how you display the MediaPlayer in your Layout, do you use a VideoView or a Surface View? What does the XML for this activity look like. Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom VideoPlayer by extending VideoView class and use it:

```
public class VideoPlayer extends VideoView {

    public VideoPlayer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            TyrooLog.i(TAG, "onMeasure");
            int width = getDefaultSize(videoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
            int height = getDefaultSize(videoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
            if (videoWidth > 0 && videoHeight > 0) {
                if (videoWidth * height > width * videoHeight) {
                    TyrooLog.i(TAG, "video too tall, correcting");
                    height = width * videoHeight / videoWidth;
                } else if (videoWidth * height < width * videoHeight) {
                    TyrooLog.i(TAG, "video too wide, correcting");
                    width = height * videoWidth / videoHeight;
                } else {
                    TyrooLog.i(TAG, "aspect ratio is correct: " + width+"/"+height+"="+mVideoWidth+"/"+mVideoHeight);
                }
            }
            TyrooLog.i(TAG, "setting size: " + width + 'x' + height);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was only happening when I used an emulator, it worked fine when i tried it on a real device